# Designing a splash screen (java)

Tags: java, swing, splash-screen, javafx-2

I want to  design a splash screen that can show the current loading process with a progress bar,
much like netbeans startup screen, as it shows

```
loading... modules, done!.... loading modules and so on
```

and after the loading finished the main application comes up.

I have read many articles that are related to only creating a splash screen but none of them addresses about How to display progress of different background tasks on a splash screen.

How can I achieve this?

Can I use javafx 2 for splash screen while the rest of the application is written using java

**Solved!**

I finally managed it to work.
**My mistake** was I was updating the GUI content in the Task Thread so My Task Thread was Blocked and could not execute the next instructions after the GUI update instructions.Now I shifted those Updating GUI instruction after Task Completion, and its working.....
Thanks Jewelsea for the right path.

Comment: Can I just weigh in to say don't do it? I don't know of anyone who actually likes splash screens - I hate it when software shoves it in my face, just load up in the background and show the window when you have it. Could just be me though.

Comment: In my view splash screens are good when your software/application takes some time to load like establishing a database connection, fetching data, so user can actually see that some processing is there.

Comment: Surely that is down to the Desktop Environment? For example, KDE displays the bouncing application icon next to the cursor to give the user feedback that the application is launching. Of course, the best option is to make it a user preference - that way you keep everyone happy.

Comment: ya exactly, my application (javafx+java) takes roughly 10 seconds to load...

Comment: any idea how does netbeans do that ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I created a [splash page sample](https://gist.github.com/1588531) for a standalone JavaFX 2.0 application previously.

I updated the sample to demonstrate monitoring of the load progress via a progress bar and progress text on the splash page.

To adapt the code to monitor the initialization progress of your application, rather than tying the `ProgressBar` to a WebEngine's `loadWorker.workDone` property, create a JavaFX [Task](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2.0/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html) which performs expensive initialization work, and monitor the progress of the `Task` via the Task's [progressProperty](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2.0/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html#progressProperty) and [messageProperty](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2.0/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html#messageProperty).

Here is a link to a [splash based sample](https://gist.github.com/2305098) based upon the Task approach outlined in the prior paragraph.

For a WebStart or browser embedded JavaFX application, use a [preloader](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2.0/api/javafx/application/Preloader.html) as suggested by assylias.

Comment: So you mean to say I have to create different Tasks for each of the background processes and display these Tasks progress property on the splash screen?

Comment: and I tried to implement it AS suppose showProcess is my splash sceen,

showProcess.progressBar.progressProperty().bind(task.workDoneProperty().divide(100));

showProcess.showVisible(true); 

task.run();


now when i run this code task does not get executed. Am I missing something?

Comment: Updated answer to link to additionally link to a task based solution.

Comment: Thanks a lot jewelsea, I finally managed it to work. :) My mistake was I was updating the GUI content in the Task Thread so My Task Thread was Blocked and could not execute the next instructions after the GUI update instructions(in my point of view). Now I shifted those Updating GUI instruction after Task Completion, and its working.....

Comment: Hi jewelsea.  Your splash sample works wonderfully.  Are there any restrictions on adopting the code in a commercial application?  Thanks.

Comment: There are no restrictions on use of the splash sample.

Comment: jewelsea - Using your example, and it works well, but I have a factory class which loads a bunch of beans (database, messaging, etc.) when called from the AnnotationConfigApplicationContext constructor and I would like to have some feedback from that, since most of the start-up time is in this constructor.  Any ideas?

Comment: @kpenrose I don't use Spring so I can't advise on that particular integration point.  In general, if you have a long running start-up task, and a requirement for it to provide intermittent progress feedback to a splash page, you can use the [task basked](https://gist.github.com/jewelsea/2305098) splash page I linked in my answer.  If you have further questions, please ask them as a new question rather than a comment.

Answer (score 4):

If you use [java-web-start](/questions/tagged/java-web-start) for deployment, the [`icon` element](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/javaws/developersguide/syntax.html#information) can refer to any of a variety of images. Progress indication is handled by the `jnlp` client during download. The advantage is intervening very early in the user experience.

Later, a `SwingWorker` can load image(s) in the background, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4530659/230513). The worker's `progress()` method can drive a `JProgressBar` via a `PropertyChangeListener`, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4637725/230513).

Answer (score 3):

Using a [preloader](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2.0/deployment/preloaders.htm#BABGGDJG) to display the progress of the application initialisation seems to be what you are looking for.

Comment: preloaders are good for WebStart and browser embedded applications, but (as of JavaFX 2.0) aren't targeted at standalone applications.

Comment: Seems like for JavaFX 2.1+, preloaders can also be used in initialization of standalone applications - but I haven't tried it out yet.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the [Swing splash-screen tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/splashscreen.html), which contains a sample where a progress bar is updated on the splash screen. You could easily adjust the sample to update some text instead.

Comment: Except you can't use Swing/AWT component such as `JProgressBar` as it will make the splash screen disappear. You have to draw it on the `SplashScreen.createGraphics()`...

Answer (score 0):

You also Create Splash Screen With java,

but if you want to code less and do more than use JavaFx Splash screen Component.

Comment: I have tried that but I want to show the progress of background process as well,

Answer (score 0):

For completeness, if you want to show a progress bar. Quoting the [`SplashScreen` javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/SplashScreen.html):

> The splash screen window is closed automatically as soon as the first
>   window is displayed by Swing/AWT.

which means it cannot use standard AWT/Swing components (such as `JProgressBar`) but can only be drawn through the [`Graphics2D`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics2D.html) methods (e.g. `drawText()`, `fillRect()`, ...).

So you'd have to emulate a progress bar in a separate class (code is given as a very rough demonstration. You should check for [`SplashScreen.isVisible()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/SplashScreen.html#isVisible--)):

```
public class SplashProgressBar {

    SplashScreen splash;
    Graphics2D g;
    int x, y, w, h; // Drawing position in splash screen

    int val, max; // Progress bar value
    String text; // Text to display

    public SplashProgressBar(SplashScreen splash, int x, int y, int w, int h) {
        this.splash = splash;
        g = splash.createGraphics();
        this.x = x;
        // this.y = y; etc
        this.val = 0;
        this.max = 100;
    }

    public void setMaximum(int n) {
        max = n;
        update();
    }

    public void setValue(int n) {
        val = n;
        update();
    }

    public void setString(String text) {
        this.text = text;
        update();
    }

    public void update() {
        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g.fillRect(x, y, w, h);
        g.setColor(Color.DARK_GRAY);
        g.drawRect(x, y, w, h);
        g.setColor(Color.ORANGE);
        g.fill3DRect(x, y, w * val / max, h, true);
        if (text != null) {
            g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g.drawString(text, x + (w - g.getFontMetrics().stringWidth(text)) / 2.0f, y + 8 - 2); // Use TextLayout to get precise text dimensions...
        }
        splash.update();
    }
}
```

Then:

```
// Drawn a scroll bar at (10;100) x (300x15) on the splash screen image (we know its size and where it would fit)
SplashProgressBar spb = new SplashProgressBar(SplashScreen.getSplashScreen(), 10, 100, 300, 15);
spb.setMaximum(processing.size());
for (int i = 0; i < processing.size(); i++) {
    spb.setValue(i);
    spb.setString("Processing #"+(i+1));
    // Do the processing...
}
```