# Allowing my JComponent to repaint() while key listener is running

Tags: java, multithreading, animation, keylistener, jcomponent

I didn't attach any code because I didn't think it was necessary if you just follow along.

I have a main class with a JComponent (component) and JFrame (frame) as fields. This class also implements runnable and once the thread is started, a game loop runs and currently the only line in that loop is component.repaint(); usually paintComponent() is constantly called and my window continues to update smoothly. I also added a keylistener to the JFrame using frame.addKeyListener(new MoveListener()); (I made MoveListener and it implements KeyListener)

The only problem is that when I hit say the "right" key and key pressed is called. Instead of having my sprite jump from one tile to the next im having him smoothly move one pixel at a time very quickly(my animation). To keep the sprite centered on the screen, when he "moves right", then I have the map move left. In key pressed, I have a for loop that subtracts 1 from the coordinates of the map each time until it reached the next tile in which case it would stop moving and everything's coordinates would be updated to the next tile.

I figured the keylistener and my thread would run independently, but when keypressed is called... the thread keeps running, but the component isn't repainting. The screen pauses for a moment as the for loop runs through and then the sprite jumps to the next tile. I've tested and im sure the thread is running and attempting to call repaint() but paintComponent() doesn't run untill after keypressed is finished.

I assumed that since they were separate threads that the component could keep painting as the listener moved the map around. Is there a reason it won't paint while the keylistener is running or did I do something else wrong because obviiously I'm not a profesional so I don't know everything about this stuff? also what is the best way to get around this...if need be Ill upload my code so you can take a look, but i think i explained pretty thoroughly. thanks for all help in advance!!

Comment: That's one long post. See if this similar post helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11918605/java-jframe-doesnt-repaint-untill-another-thread-is-finished

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have a for loop that subtracts 1 from the coordinates of the map

Would suggest that you blocking the event dispatching thread, which is responsible for processing paint requests AND key event (amongst other things)

This means that while the loo in `keyPressed` is been executed, nothing else will be processed, including the repaint request.

Before you comment that you are painting the component from a separate thread, you're not, actually.  What happens is you make a paint request to the `RepaintManager`, which places a repaint request into the event queue, which is then processed by the Event Dispatching Thread

What I suggest you do, is raise some kind of flag in keyPressed event method.  You would, then monitor for this flag in the game thread and update the state of the map on each iteration of the thread loop until the end state is meet and/or some kind of event changes the state of the flag, for example...

You might like to take. Look at [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) and [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more details

And while I'm here, I would encourage you to use [key bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) over `KeyListener` as it has better control over the focus requirements

Comment: Thanks that explained a lot about it being in the same thread... but even when I write repaint directly in the loop in keypressed it still never updates until after the loop ends and I've using things like Swingmanager.repaint()  perhaps the repaint requests are being called so fast they're all be grouped into one repaint once the loop is done? even though ive had it sleep in the loop to slow it down

Comment: That's because your still blocking the EDT. Repaint requests are added to the event queue, so while your loop is running in the key listener, the EDT can't process the event queue, meaning nothing happens...ever...

Comment: The RepaintManager is highly optimised and can consolidate repaint requests into less calls, this helps improve the speed of repainting in swing in general terms. Simple. Don't block the EDT, use your game loop to update the the state of UI and the EDT/components to render this state

Comment: ok exactly how would I do that without having the loop in key listener? like have the key set a boolean "moving" true and then have it move one pixel every cycle of my game loop until it reaches the next tile then switch it back to false or something like that so the thread continues to run though... because once i set that boolean, then keypressed() can terminate and "free up" the EDT?

Comment: I'm pretty sure I get the concept well enough to try a few different things with it thanks for all the explanation and sticking with me