# How to load splash for e(fx)clipse?

Tags: eclipse, javafx, efxclipse

I am moving my e4 rcp application( SWT + jface) to **pure** **[e(fx)clipse](https://www.eclipse.org/efxclipse/index.html)** (JavaFX) and I want a splash screen in application with progress bar like eclipse do have.

Can anyone suggest what should i do?

I Checked [this answer from tom](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15130532/2691625) but I didn't understand where I can load stage in **e(fx)clipse** application?

[Edit:1]
As of now there is not Progress bar support for e(fx)clipse. And [**This**](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/1068337/?) helps to load splash with minimum efforts for novice.

[Edit:2]
One more thing i have observed as mentioned in [forum](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/1068337/). 
Splash screen is visible at background to application.

Comment: Did you go through [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15148611/1759128) ?

Comment: Yes, I went but i don't have Application class to override start() or stop() method. I Checked [this](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=418399) too. But didn't get how to make extension and resolve.

Comment: I don't get it, how can you have a JavaFX application without extending the Application class?

Comment: For e(fx)clipse there is default class which is part of **bundle(OSGI)** `org.eclipse.fx.ui.workbench.fx.E4Application`.  Do You have any idea about how can i simply extend and implement my own **Application** class and point application class in plugin.xml?

Comment: I have never worked with OSGi or in that matter E4Application class. I have used efxclipse plugin for eclipse for few features that were helpful in my JavaFX application. I am not sure which *plugin.xml* you are talking about. I know you can easily make a Splash screen for your JavaFX application but I cannot relate what it has to do with efxclipse. May be I am missing something or you should wait for someone who is more experience in this field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all yes OSGi-Application built on e4-JavaFX don't implement the Application class themselves because this needs to be done as part of the OSGi-Lifecycle.

Once you accepted this situation you have multiple choices:

- you bring up a kind of splash through the lifecycle hook with the caveat that it gets up after JavaFX and OSGi have been initialized which might take some time
- if you are on windows/linux you can still use the equinox hook with the only caveat that we bring this one done very early because we can not bring it down on the JavaFX thread
- you adjust the bootstrapping of Equinox-OSGi-Applications and do the launch yourself

If you really want to discuss this stuff in depth than I suggest you post to our forum - https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/f/259/