# How to change the StageStyle in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

is it possible to change the StageStyle from `StageStyle.UNIFIED' to 'StageStyle.UTILITY' when the stage is already Active

my code for stage creation :

```
Stage PrimaryStage= new Stage(StageStyle.UTILITY);
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/InterfacePack/User_Management_Login.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        stage.setTitle("-: Login :-");
        PrimaryStage.setScene(scene);
        PrimaryStage.show();
```

i want to change the stagestyle in following code :

```
  stage = (Stage) LoginButton.getScene().getWindow();
                Parent root = null;
                try {
                    root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/InterfacePack/User_Management_fx.fxml"));
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(User_Management_LoginController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
                Scene scene = new Scene(root);
                Toolkit kit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
                Dimension dim = kit.getScreenSize();
                stage.setHeight(dim.getHeight());
                stage.setWidth(dim.getWidth());
                stage.setResizable(false);
                stage.setMaximized(true);
                stage.setScene(scene);
                stage.setTitle("Automation Of Real Estate Construction Company");
                stage.show();
```

How should i Implement it..?? Please Help..

Comment: You should close the existing stage and open a new one, if you want a different `StageStyle`

Comment: possible duplicate of [java fx java.lang.IllegalStateException (Stage)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27069384/java-fx-java-lang-illegalstateexception-stage)

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't do change the style of a stage when it is already `Active / Showing`

From the docs

> The style must be initialized before the stage is made visible.

You can read the section on *Styles* from the [Stage API Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/Stage.html)