# Use of SwingWorker to do complex tasks in background

Tags: java, swingworker

I am having a GUI of login screen. Whenever i press the login button the user name and password is checked against entry in an online mysql database,i'm extracting all this information from database in actionPerformed() method of the login button.Problem is while program is fetching data from database the GUI freezes.I googled my problem and found that i should use SwingWorker but being a newbie i didn't get how to use SwingWorker for my purpose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, declare a member variable in your class (it could be in your GUI class) of type `SwingWorker` like this:

```
private SwingWorker<Boolean, Void> backgroundProcess;
```

Then initialize the variable in your initialization code (constructor, onShow method event handler, etc) like this:

```
    backgroundProcess = new SwingWorker<Boolean, Void>() {

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground() throws Exception {
            // paste the MySQL code stuff here
        }

        @Override
        protected void done() {
            // Process ended, mark some ended flag here
            // or show result dialog, messageBox, etc      
        }
    };
```

Then, in your `actionPerfomed` method, call the `SwingWorker`'s execute method:

```
    backgroundProcess.execute();
```

If done correctly, the GUI shouldn't freezee after the button press event

Comment: +1 for a helpful outline, but I don't understand using `Boolean`. Wouldn't a `Connection` or `DataSource` be more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

This simple [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4530659/230513) `extends SwingWorker<Icon, Void>` to fetch an `Icon` with `Void` intermediate results. Similarly, yours might extend `SwingWorker<DataSource, Void>` to fetch a [`DataSource`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sql/DataSource.html).

Comment: You mean that i have to fetch data from DB in doInBackground() method and call the execute() method when user clicks on the login button.

Comment: Yes; `done()` executes on the EDT, so you can update you GUI once you get a connection,

Comment: how can in get value returned from doInBackground() in done() method?
I want to show a new JFrame if it reurns true and show an error message if it returns false.Do i need another EDT in done to show new frame?

Comment: @SushilKumar the easy way is to declare a member variable inside the `SwingWorker` declaration (after the `new SwingWorker<Boolean, Void>() {` line), you can reference that variable in both  doInBackground and done methods

Comment: @h3nr1x is correct; the example cited includes an `ImageIcon` member variable.