# actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

Tags: java, awt, action, actionevent

I am building a grpahic interface with different buttons,
and when user clicks a button I use :

```
actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
Object source = e.getSource();
if
else if
else if
...
}
```

The problem is that when the user clicks a button, `actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)` is called, and it enter in the if corresponding to `e.getSource();`. 
And it executes all instructions in the corresponding if. But I want to make possible that the user clicks different buttons, so that a `actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)` { is called, even if the instructions of the previous `actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)` { is not finish yet.

I don't know if you understand, but thank you if you can help me !

Answer (score 5):

You will need to use background threads if you want the GUI to be responsive while a long-running process is occurring. A SwingWorker works well for this in Swing GUI's. Please check out [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) for all the gory details on this.

Examples:

- [mvc-progress-bar-threading](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5533581)
- [why-does-swingworker-stop-unexpectedly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14900697/why-does-swingworker-stop-unexpectedly/14900792#14900792)
- [Google Search](https://www.google.com/#hl=en&sclient=psy-ab&q=site:stackoverflow.com+hovercraftfullofeels+swingworker+doinbackground)

Comment: @Natacha: yep, tons of examples. Please search this site with my name and the key word *SwingWorker* to see some of them.

Comment: @Natacha: one way is to simply use Google: [Google Search](https://www.google.com/#hl=en&sclient=psy-ab&q=site:stackoverflow.com+hovercraftfullofeels+swingworker+doinbackground). Some links posted above in answer.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `SwingWorker` . It does the work in background without freezing the UI.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11255925/use-of-swingworker-to-do-complex-tasks-in-background) is the question you can have a look for how to use them.
Or you can use official oracle [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) for `SwingWorker`.