# Occasionally NullPointerException

Tags: java, swing

I have a java app and I get occasionally a `java.lang.NullPointerException`. I have this app working in kiosks and when this error happen, it get stuck and cause a lot of problems.

The error is:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javax.swing.ImageIcon.<init>(ImageIcon.java:204)
    at GUI.newCardPanel.backButton1MousePressed(newCardPanel.java:1470)
    at GUI.newCardPanel.access$11000(newCardPanel.java:36)
    at GUI.newCardPanel$64.mousePressed(newCardPanel.java:1091)
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mousePressed(AWTEventMulticaster.java:280)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6386)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3268)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6154)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2045)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4750)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2103)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4576)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4633)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4294)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4227)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2089)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2518)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4576)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:672)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:96)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:631)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:629)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:105)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:645)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:643)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:642)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:275)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:200)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:190)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:185)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:177)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
```

The line 1470:

```
backButton1.setIcon(new ImageIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/imagenes/sing-in-pres.png")).getImage()));
```

```
public class newCardPanel extends javax.swing.JPanel  { //This one is the 36
```

1091: (Auto generated code by Netbeans)

```
public void mousePressed(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
            backButton1MousePressed(evt);   //This one is the 1091
        }
```

The images are in the `src` folder.

Comment: You're using an ImageIcon to construct an ImageIcon? Why? Also, please make sure that `new ImageIcon` actually returns an object. You know, just to make sure. Actually, do that check on `getResource` already. Chances are, that it can't find the resource you have it looking for.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a look at the source for ImageIcon you will see:

```
public ImageIcon (URL location) {
    this(location, location.toExternalForm());
}
```

Which means you are passing in a null value for URL.
Which means your code at

```
getClass().getResource("/imagenes/sing-in-pres.png")
```

is returning null.

Debug from there.

Comment: I cannot make debug since this problem happen occasionally. I can't find any way to replicate the problem. It just happen sometimes and I have the log of everything

Answer (score 1):

> It just happen *sometimes*.

*Sometimes* may be the result of faulty synchronization. Swing GUI objects should be constructed and manipulated *only* on the [event dispatch thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html). Access to shared data *must* be synchronized. [`SwingWorker`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html) is one approach to keeping the GUI responsive while loading images in the background, for [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4530659/230513).

Comment: I just checked that i can replicate the issue here. The one that happens sometimes is this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15348872/nullpointerexception-sometimes

Comment: That does not eliminate faulty synchronization as the root cause. Try a different machine or look at the approaches cited [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7787998/230513).