# sun.awt.image.ImageFetcher.run taking too long

Tags: java, swing, awt

I just inherited a desktop application that is under performing on simple tasks. Running jvisualvm to profile the code I noticed the method [`sun.awt.image.ImageFetcher.run`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/sun/awt/image/ImageFetcher.java#ImageFetcher.run%28%29) is responsible for the majority of the time, taking over 5 seconds when displaying a simple form.

I checked the entire codebase and the only images were small png icons (< 1kb each) and the icons from awt itself, and found no reference to external images.

What could be happening here? Is `ImageFetcher` triggering other code (which the profiler doesn't show) or is there some reason for image loading taking this long?

Comment: I don't know the answer to either of your questions.  OTOH they will be hard to answer given the completely undocumented nature of the `sun` classes.  **Don't use them.**  I would not be surprised if using the public methods fixes the delay.

Comment: You may be encountering network latency, as suggested [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18775456/230513).

Comment: @AndrewThompson The application does not use `sun` classes directly. @trashgod I'm still looking for, but I don't see any references to web resources.

Comment: Only one person can be notified at a time.  Given I was notified, I presume that @trashgod was not..

Comment: Thanks for telling me, but it's still kinda far from solving the problem. I found a few classes that could theoretically connect to the internet, but they are not being called.

Comment: @AndrewThompson: I saw it. BopperH: it looks like the image fetcher is blocking the EDT.

Comment: I had a similar situation (with OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM build 23.7-b01) when a JIT compiler stopped working for no apparent reason. I guessed that UnsatisfiedLinkError and other class loading issues might be the reason and after I fixed those the JIT works stable once again.