# Progress bar for loading out another JFrame class

Tags: java, swing, progress-bar, listener

I have 2 JFrame: `NewJFrame` and `NewJFrame1`. `NewJFrame`  has a progress bar and a button. the button is used to call up `NewJFrame1`. When the button is clicked it should trigger the progress bar to run until `NewJFrame1` pop up. However, how do I make use of the swing worker and let the progress to run until `NewJFrame1` actually competely loaded all of its component?

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        int i = 0;
        public void run() {
           jProgressBar1.setValue(i++);
           new NewJFrame1().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9554657/418556)

Comment: I created the 2 JFrame just for testing purpose. but thanks, I'll implement using JDialog and JFrame for real

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let your [top-level container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toplevel.html) have a `SwingWorker` that loads it's content, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4530659/230513), and a `PropertyChangeListener`, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4637725/230513). When `doInBackground()` calls `setProgress()`, the listener will see the event.

Addendum: *How do we know how much time left for the GUI to be completely loaded? …in examples, the progress bar is run with random number as simulated latency*.

Correct; the simulated latency represents the granularity of your loading. Displaying the fraction of total bytes loaded would be ideal, but you may have to settle for a coarser frequency. Note that models may be constructed in the background, *before* any components are listening. GUI components should be constructed and manipulated only on the EDT, possibly in the worker's `process()` implementation.

Comment: how do we know how much time left for the GUI to be completely loaded?
So far as what i've been research from the net examples, the progress bar is run with random number as simulated latency