# How to add a ToolTip to MapMarker in JMapViewer

Tags: java, jmapviewer

I'm trying to add a `ToolTip` to a custom `MapMarker` on *JMapViewer*. But repeaded searches on are not helping me solve this.

The custom *MapMarker* is:

```
public class MapMarkerUnit extends MapObjectImpl implements MapMarker
```

and the Paint Method overide is

```
public void paint(Graphics g, Point position, int radio) {
    String filename = "marker.png";
    //System.out.print(filename);
    BufferedImage x = null;
    try {
        x = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource(filename));
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(MapMarkerUnit.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

    g.drawImage(x, position.x-16, position.y-37,null);

    //if(getLayer()==null||getLayer().isVisibleTexts()) paintText(g, new       Point(position.x+20,position.y));
}
```

Thanks for any help your able to offer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Override the `getToolTipText()` method of `JMapViewer`. In your implementation, use `getPosition()` to convert the `MouseEvent` coordinates into geodetic coordinates. The example below simply displays the unformatted coordinates; you'll want to find the nearest `MapMarker` and return the appropriate text.

```
JMapViewer map = new JMapViewer() {

    @Override
    public String getToolTipText(MouseEvent e) {
        Coordinate c = getPosition(e.getX(), e.getY());
        return c.getLat() + " " + c.getLon();
    }
};
map.setToolTipText(""); // initialize
```

Addendum: *Is there a way of adding a tooltip directly to an image?*

No; `JMapViewer` is the enclosing `JComponent` that handles tool tips.

*I have about 50 markers on the map…that's a lot of iterations.*

You definitely can't load images in your `MapMarker` implementation; use a [`SWingWorker`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html) to load images in the background, for [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4530659/230513).

As a concrete iteration example, `JFreeChart` easily handles tool tips for scores of entities in this way. Here's the enclosing panel's [`getToolTipText()`](https://github.com/jfree/jfreechart/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jfree/chart/swing/ChartPanel.java#L1277) implementation, and here's the [loop](https://github.com/jfree/jfreechart/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jfree/chart/entity/StandardEntityCollection.java#L135) that invokes `Shape#contains()`. A simplified example that illustrates the approach is seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53609066/230513).

Comment: Thanks for the example - I have about 50 markers on the map, so that's a lot of iterations every time the mouse moves on the map. Is there a way of adding a tooltip directly to an image? I was going to try with using a 'jLabel' with an icon to the map but I don't believe they can be shown on a jMapViewer

Comment: I've elaborated above.

Comment: That's excellent - Thanks for pointing me towards such a concrete example. I'll look to implement it like this. Thanks for your time and help!

Comment: Implemented your suggestion and it worked perfectly! many thanks for all your help.