# Add mouse event to JMapViewer mapMarker

Tags: java, swing, awt, jmapviewer

How can I add mouseListener to a MapMarker (MepMarkerDot or MapMarkerCircle) that makes it like button?
I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24688091/2616306) soloution but it makes whole map clickable (mouse Event works on all the map).

Comment: Consider adding the Swing tag to this question.

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right path to start with [TrashGod's MouseListener solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24688091/522444), but you need to add a little more code, the key part being, that you need to get the Point location of where the user pressed, something the `MouseEvent#getPoint()` method will tell you, and then based on that information, and the bounds of the "active" area of the component decide whether to respond. Something like:

```
@Override
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
    Point p = e.getPoint(); // this is where the user pressed
    if (isPointValid(p)) {
        // do something
    }
    System.out.println(map.getPosition(e.getPoint()));
}

private boolean isPointValid(Point p) {
    // here you have code to decide if the point was pressed in the area of interest.
}
```

Note that if your code uses Shape derived objects, such as Ellipse2D or Rectangle2D, you can use their `contains(Point p)` method to easily tell you if the point press was within the Shape or not. Or if there are several locations that you want to check, you may have a collection of Shapes, iterate through them within your mousePressed or (if you have it) isPointValid method, and check containment within the for loop.

Comment: Correct; a hit-testing scheme using `Shape#contains()` is cited [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25944439/230513).

Comment: I think it does not use shape derived objects. MapMarkerCircle is a class that extends MapObjImpl abstract class. It has a paint(Graphics g, Point position, int radio) method. 

http://svn.openstreetmap.org/applications/viewer/jmapviewer/src/org/openstreetmap/gui/jmapviewer/MapMarkerCircle.java

Comment: @s_puria: if has position, then you can create your own code test to see if the click is on or near one of these objects, and I suggest that you try to do just that.

Answer (score 0):

I found this nice example:

https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?source_dir=netention-old1-master/swing/automenta/netention/swing/map/Map2DPanel.java

It has an interface MarkerClickable and its own LabeledMarker which implements MapMarker and MarkerClickable:

```
    public boolean onClick(final Coordinate p, final MouseEvent e) { 
    for (final MapMarker x : getMap().getMapMarkerList()) { 
        if (x instanceof MarkerClickable) { 
            final MarkerClickable mc = (MarkerClickable)x; 
            final Rectangle a = mc.getClickableArea(); 
            if (a == null) 
                continue; 

            if (a.contains(e.getPoint())) { 
                mc.onClicked(e.getPoint(), e.getButton()); 
                return false; 
            } 
        } 
    } 
    return true; 
}
```