# Java Swing JSlider (Vertical) changing thumbRect messes up slider control

Tags: java, swing, jslider

I'm trying to override paintThumb to show a graphic slider thumb. As long as I don't mess with size of the image and let it paint according to the existing size of the thumb the thumb image and slider functions fine. If I change the size of thumbRect or my image, I cannot grab thumb or moving the slider not longer works. This is a vertical JSlider.

NOTE:  Thanks to trashgod for the solution. See in code.
NOTE2: UPDATED TO NOW BE A WORKING ACCEPTABLE EXAMPLE.
NOTE3: Original problem was caused by doing resize inside paintThumb.

Here's the slider:

```
sliders[channel].setUI(new customSliderHandle(sliders[channel], busType));
```

Here's the class:

```
private static class customSliderHandle extends BasicSliderUI {

    String sBusType;
    Image image;

    public customSliderHandle(JSlider slider, String busType) {
        super(slider);

        sBusType = busType;

        try {
            if(sBusType.equals("ch")) {
                //noinspection ConstantConditions
                image = ImageIO.read(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("web/images/black-slider.png"));
            } else {
                //noinspection ConstantConditions
                image = ImageIO.read(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("web/images/yellow-slider.png"));
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void calculateThumbSize() {
        super.calculateThumbSize();

        //// Fixed!!!
        thumbRect.setSize(20, 40);
    }

    @Override
    public void paintThumb(Graphics g) {

        ///// This was the original problem. Move into
        ///// calculateThumbSize() resolved the problem.
        ///// thumbRect.setSize(20, 40);

        int x = thumbRect.x;
        int y = thumbRect.y;
        int width = thumbRect.width;
        int height = thumbRect.height;
        g.drawImage(image, x, y, width, height, null);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the time `paintThumb()` is called, [`BasicSliderUI`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/plaf/basic/BasicSliderUI.html#getThumbSize--) has already calculated `thumbRect` based on the result of `getThumbSize()`. Moreover, because of its unknown latency, you should not invoke`ImageIO.read()` inside `paint()`. Instead, load the image asynchronously, perhaps using `SwingWorker` as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4530659/230513), and use the image's dimensions in your implementation of `getThumbSize()`. Note that you should take the result of `getOrientation()` into account if your `image` is not square.

Comment: I so appreciate SO and those that help! I just put thumbRect.setSize(20,40) in calculateThumbSize() override and it worked. Not sure exactly how to simplify the image handling but this is definitely the answer. I'll update my OP

Comment: If I move the ImageIO out of paintThumb and into the parent method (customSliderHandle) and place the declaration in the class (like I did with sBusType) will that be ok?

Comment: @JohnSmith: Passing a reference in the constructor sounds right.